# Modificar HTML con JS

Tags: javascript, html

necesito escribir un HTML con tres divs vacios (sin contenido) y darle un texto desde Javascript (al cargar la pagina).
el contenido debe ser igual para los 3 divs, no logro hacer que me tome los 3 aunque ponga querySelectoAll.

Comment: Podrias colocar tu codigo, así podremos decirte que es lo que estás haciendo mal, pues solo describes el problemas no indicas donde surge  ni que es lo has hecho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trata de ponerle una misma `class` a los tres `<div>` y luego con `document.querySelectorAll()` genera un `nodeList` que puedes iterar y cambiar el contenido de cada `<div>`:

```
<body>

  <div class="contenido"></div>
  <div class="contenido"></div>
  <div class="contenido"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    const divToChange = document.querySelectorAll('.contenido');
    for (div of divToChange){
      div.innerHTML = 'Cambio!';
    }
  </script>

</body>
```

Resultado:

```
Cambio!
Cambio!
Cambio!
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer algo con jQuery como esto

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   <div id="div1"></div>

   <div id="div2"></div>

   <div id="div3"></div>

   <script type="text/javascript">

    var texto = "TEXTO";
    
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#div1").text("EJEMPLO");
         $("#div2").text("EJEMPLO");
         $("#div3").text("EJEMPLO");
     });

   </script>
```